# Text on Img - without using height/width

Tags: html, css

i want to place Text on an img (centered vertically and horizontally).
I have tried a lot of stuff. The problem is the img and the text can change. Also the img have to be floated next to each other.

Here is an example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/h5az77hd/1/

```
<div id="div0">
    <div class="div1">
        <div class="div2">
            <div class="div3">Start</div>
            <img src="http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150222/w4d322gc.png" style="display:block;" width="auto" height="150">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div1">
        <div class="div2">
            <div class="div3">Testtext</div>
            <img src="http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150222/w4d322gc.png" style="display:block;" width="auto" height="150">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.div1 {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.div2 {
    float: left; 
    background:#2E2EFE;
}

.div3{
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

---

I cant use margin/width/height/... settings (bcs the text and img can change)

Are you guys having an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I need to center things without knowing it's width / height I use a combination of `display: table` `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` and `text-align: center`.

When you have a parent with `display: table;` and a children with `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`, the children will be at the middle (vertically) of table, then, just use `text-align: center;` to center things horizontally.

In this case, you will need to adjust some things in your markup to make it works.

Here is a demo (using your image): http://jsfiddle.net/499nhjb0/1/

In your case, you can try to change `.div3` to behaviour as `.container-text-wrapper`.

Hope it helps!